# 100% height table resets scroll offset

Tags: html, scroll, resize

This is more like a question of principle.

I made a table with 100% width and height to make 3 rows nice and auto-resizable (welcome to xhtml :D).

When I begin to toggle() some elements, the total size of the page changes, and my browser resets its scroll offset and scrolls all the way to the top of the page.

Is there some way to prevent scrolling, except making a JS function to calculate the scroll offset and make it jump to its previous offset? I don´t want to mess around with 3 divs, trying to align them automatically in their height.

Comment: plz post the relevant html/js/css to help visualize the situation

Comment: I was going to post these 3 obvious lines of code as is saw it:
<a href="#" onclick="someFunction()">...</a>
Adding a "#" makes my browser think its an anchor. No scroll offset reset at all. God I´m stupid.

Comment: Well, it **is** an anchor. ;) It still is, without the href. Interesting enough, the style changes without the href.

Comment: works perfectly without the href="#". style does not change with following CSS code:
a, a:visited, a:active { color:#3270e1; outline:0; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; }

a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete href="#" :P

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
html
        {
            overflow:scroll;
        }
```

to your CSS, or playing with those settings.